# Form for object with computed property in terms of a navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, calculated-field, computed-properties

## Context

Here's a model class:

```
    public class HealthRecord
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

        public int FoodItemId { get; set; }

        public FoodItem FoodItem { get; set; } // navigation

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public decimal Calories => FoodItem.Calories * Amount;
    }
```

Note that the following is a calculated property:

```
public decimal Calories => FoodItem.Calories * Amount;
```

And that `FoodItem` is a navigation property.

## The issue

If I fill out the create form for a new `HealthRecord` object:

[image]

and press `Create`, I get the following:

[image]

## Note 1

I set a breakpoint on `CreateModel.OnPostAsync` in my `HealthRecords` page model. However, it appears that it doesn't even get that far.

## Note 2

It seems that ASP.NET Core is, for some reason, trying to access the `HealthRecord.Calories` property of the object that results from submitting the form, but the `FoodItem` property on that object is still null (although `FoodItemId` *is* set).

So for example, if I simply comment out the calculated property in `HealthRecord`:

```
// public decimal Calories => FoodItem.Calories * Amount;
```

the create form works.

Similarly, we can add a null check on `FoodItem` as a workaround:

```
public decimal Calories => FoodItem != null ? FoodItem.Calories * Amount : 0;
```

## Question

It seems the null-check above is a kludge and shouldn't be necessary.

What's a good way to allow for the `Calories` property to exist and for the form to still work properly?

## Project

Whole project on github: [link](https://github.com/dharmatech/NutritionTrackerRazorPages-2021-05-25/tree/207fe6b20473132b46d02b7a787e272648b5b70f)

`HealthRecord` class:

[Models/HealthRecord.cs](https://github.com/dharmatech/NutritionTrackerRazorPages-2021-05-25/blob/207fe6b20473132b46d02b7a787e272648b5b70f/Models/HealthRecord.cs)

Page model for `HealthRecord` create page:

[HealthRecords/Create.cshtml.cs](https://github.com/dharmatech/NutritionTrackerRazorPages-2021-05-25/blob/207fe6b20473132b46d02b7a787e272648b5b70f/Pages/HealthRecords/Create.cshtml.cs)

## Update

[Charleh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987509/charleh) in a comment below suggests the following:

```
[ValidateNever]
public decimal Calories => FoodItem.Calories * Amount;
```

And yes, it does seem to work!

This property is mentioned here:

[Advanced \ Model validation \ Built-in attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#built-in-attributes)

Comment: Most likely there's an ignore attribute you can apply to tell the model binder to ignore the property when generating the POST data. I'm trying to dig up the info...

Comment: Ok, since this appears to be the validation namespace, there's an attribute called `ValidateNever` you can apply: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.validateneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0 - however, I'm not sure if the binder will still try to serialize the property as part of the post data, so try adding this attribute first and seeing how you get on.

Comment: @Charleh, yes it works! I've updated the question to include your suggestion.

Comment: @Charleh, Consider adding a paypal or bitcoin address to your profile so I can buy you lunch. :-)

Comment: no worries man, don't worry about the lunch - I went shopping yesterday :)